# Kafka Consumer won't start consuming, current offset value is empty

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a working topic-consumer setup in kafka. While trying to create the same in another environment, the consumer does not start reading from the topic. I've tried restarting, deleting, renaming and many things but none of them worked.

When I describe the consumer group with the command `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` I got this result:

```
GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG          
G__BRC_SENDSMS  BRC_SENDSMS     0          -               31              -
```

Mind how current offset is not zero. Since it is not zero, there is also no lag too. Is this normal? What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify "working topic-consumer setup".

Answer (score 0):

> create the same in another environment

Only **one** consumer in `group.id=G__BRC_SENDSMS` can read from `BRC_SENDSMS`, partition `0` at the same time.  Change the group id, and it should start to read data. Or add more partitions to the topic, and you should see the group rebalance and distribute messages between all consumer instances. If neither work, then check networking configurations in this "other environment", such as the Kafka `advertised.listeners`.

If there is no current offset, then has your consumer actually committed yet?